# ASIO Attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have the following error:

```
Error   C2280   'Sender::Sender(const Sender &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

This is my code:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "asio.hpp"

using namespace asio;

class Sender
{
    public:
        Sender(io_service& io_service, 
               const std::string& host, 
               const std::string& port) :
                    io_service_(io_service), 
                    socket_(io_service, ip::udp::endpoint(ip::udp::v4(), 0)) 
        {
            ip::udp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
            ip::udp::resolver::query query(ip::udp::v4(), host, port);
            ip::udp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
            endpoint_ = *iter;
        };

        ~Sender() 
        {
            socket_.close();
        };

        void operator()() 
        {
            std::string msg = "";
            for (;;) 
            {
                std::cout << "Message: ";
                std::cin >> msg;
                std::cout << "The value you entered is " << msg << std::endl;
            }
        }

    private:
        io_service& io_service_;
        ip::udp::socket socket_;
        ip::udp::endpoint endpoint_;

};
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
io_service io_service;

Sender s{ io_service, "localhost", "1337" };
std::thread sender_thread{ s };    
sender_thread.join();
```

I know that it's because one of the private members can't be copied, but I can't figure out how to fix it! I don't want to implement a copy constructor.

Comment: It looks like the `sender_thread` might be trying to create a copy of `s`, but with the copy constructor being deleted, it fails.

Comment: @M.M there is no `sender_thread` constructor, it's the std lib thread!

Comment: @callyalater How do I fix this? Do I need to provide my own copy constructor?

Comment: You might have to. I don't know if `Sender(const Sender&) = default;` would work.

Answer (score 2):

`Sender` is moveable but not copyable because `boost::asio`'s socket is moveable but not copyable (see documentation).

You will need to `std::move()` your sender into the thread's constructor.

Comment: I'm calling `std::thread sender_thread{ std::move(s) };` but it's giving me the same error.

Comment: @moe2801 you might need to put `Sender(Sender&&) = default;` in - user-defined destructor suppresses implicit move constructor

Comment: It's not that. It's the presence of the destructor preventing the auto-generation of the move constructor. An Asio socket will auto-close on deletion so the destructor is unnecessary